# How to properly modify packet fields, and update ip/eth checksums?

Tags: network-programming, dpdk

I change the packet source port and IP address for my little NAT implementation like this (the packet is in `struct rte_mbuf *m`):

```
eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, struct ether_hdr *);
ipv4_hdr->dst_addr = f->int_src_ip;
```

Is it a proper way to modify the package? If so, how do I update the checksum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's the usual way. You can modify the checksum using [checksum API of DPDK](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__ip_8h.html#aafd3e9481bf3fca20ccb193c4e53d91c).

Example:

```
ipv4_hdr = (struct ipv4_hdr *)(eth_hdr + 1);
udp_hdr = (struct udp_hdr *)((char *)ipv4_hdr + sizeof(struct ipv4_hdr));
udp_hdr->src_port = 42;
ipv4_hdr->hdr_checksum = 0;
udp_hdr->dgram_cksum = 0;
udp_hdr->dgram_cksum = rte_ipv4_udptcp_cksum(ipv4_hdr, udp_hdr);
ipv4_hdr>hdr_checksum = rte_ipv4_cksum(ipv4_hdr);
```